# Return statement for simple division with where request

Tags: c#, return

I'm trying to write a very simple algorithm that will return a numeric value for a simple division with a where requirement.

So I want a small script to do the following:

```
return (x/y when y < 10) if Y > 10 return 0 or null;
```

Should be fairly easy but i cant quite nail it down. Also, can I add decimals into this? This is for a tool that pulls metrics from the internet and then converts them into another metric for me to use.

THIS IS IN C#**

figured it out!

Comment: Which language, environnement, framework.... ??

Comment: Without knowing what language or anything you're using it's impossible to help. I'm not quite sure what the confusion is, though; regardless of language what's wrong with `if (y < 10) return x/y; if (y > 10) return 0; return null;`? No clue what you mean by "adding decimals".

Comment: This is in C#  so i don think that would work

Comment: @ThePandaCats ... The constructs are essentially identical; use your imagination a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x,y) match {
   case (a,b) if b < 10 => a/b
   case (a,b) if b > 10 => 0
   case _ => null // b == 10 here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I want a small script

You may want to use ternary-if:

```
return (y < 10 ? (x/y) : 0);  //Either you return 0 or null, you decide
```

The above will return `(x/y)` if `y < 10`, else if `y is >= 10`, return `0`.

---

**Note**: You missed out a condition for `y==10`;